# how to get photo compleet url form form in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, photo, picker

I am trying to use jquery to take a picture from my comp via a form.
- So I want the entire URL out of the form in an array

- It works + / - in Dreamweaver, but not in the explorer browsers not even chrome
- The end goal is a calendar with picture / app for people with disabilities, but as long as I get to go through the phone gap

  ```
  var foto= new Array();
  var i=-1;
  //foto=["toets.png"]; 
  $('#fotouit').append("FOTO UIT");       
  $('#knop01').click(function(){
    $('input:file[name=foto]').each(function(){
      //alert($(this).val());
      foto.push($(this).val());
      foto.forEach( function(){
        i++;
        $('#fotouit').append(foto[i]); 
        $('#fotouit').append('<img src=" '+ foto[i] + ' " width="100" height="100" />');
      });
    });
  })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get the URL of the picture in you computer's local filesystem, but you can use Javascript's [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the contents of the uploaded file (in your case, the picture). The read contents can be used in the `src` of the `img` element as you did in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an in depth explanation of what you're trying to accomplish: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

**Example:**

```
function handleFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.classList.add("obj");
        img.file = file;
        preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is a the div output where the content will be displayed.

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- You can use the multiple attribute on a file input to allow selecting many files with one input
- You can use the file inputs change event to immediately capture the files rather than providing a second button to click